# Is it possible to use JBoss Rewrite without war-file?

Tags: java, maven, url-rewriting, jboss

Is it possible to use a rewrite.properties and jboss-web.xml outside of a war-file?

Currently I put both files into the WEB-INF in my war-file and it works as intended. But integration tests (with Maven) will fail, because they are redirected to the real website instead of using the version in test.

My domain points directly to the context path of the war-file, if it matters. I'm using JBoss 7.1.1.

I tried to just put both files on the server beside the war-file, but that doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I moved the configuration to standalone.xml (for OpenShift users, it's located in folder `.openshift/config`). There is very less documentation about the XML format for url rewriting, so I'm showing my config as example code.

```
    <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:web:1.1" default-virtual-server="default-host"
               native="false">
        <connector name="http" protocol="HTTP/1.1" scheme="http" socket-binding="http"/>
        <virtual-server name="default-host" enable-welcome-root="false">
            <alias name="localhost"/>
            <!-- Redirect all subdomains including naked domain to www subdomain. -->
            <!-- RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.example\.org$ [NC] -->
            <!-- RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.org/$1 [R=301,L] -->
            <rewrite pattern="^(.*)$" substitution="http://www.example.org$1" flags="R=301,L">
                <condition test="%{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="!^www\.example\.org$" flags="NC"/>
            </rewrite>

            <!-- Redirect from HTTP to HTTPS. -->
            <!-- RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} http -->
            <!-- RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L] -->
            <rewrite pattern=".*" substitution="https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}" flags="R,L">
                <condition test="%{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto}" pattern="http" flags="NC"/>
            </rewrite>
        </virtual-server>
    </subsystem>
```

Maybe those two rules could be optimized, but I had problems with a redirect cycle and this is what worked for me.

Comment: Good example, I'm trying to find a dang example to change the http_request method from GET to POST, as you can likely guess nigh near impossible to find any good examples :-/